# Vaadin Comobox not sending changeEvent

Tags: java, user-interface, vaadin, combobox

I have 3 comboboxes. Two of them works great but my third is not sending change events to my listeners, however, if I do select the empty row(null select) then I get the event. Has anyone had this problem before? In my code below the none working is the companyCombobox and the working is the personCombobox

**Some further info about the code**

Regarding the code, the comboboxes depend on each others selections, if one value is selected in combo1 then some given entities are loaded into combo2 and combo3. If you start by selecting combo2 then combo1 and combo3 should update there datasources.
The setPersonCompanyComboDataSource() is called everytime a change event occurs. I do not include this part of the code.

```
 private void initComboBoxes() {
        personCombo = getComboBox("orderwiz.orderheadstep.contactwiz.personComboBoxTitle", "orderwiz.orderheadstep.contactwiz.personComboBox");
        companyCombo = getComboBox("orderwiz.orderheadstep.contactwiz.companyComboBoxTitle", "orderwiz.orderheadstep.contactwiz.companyComboBox");
        contactInfoCombo = getComboBox("orderwiz.orderheadstep.contactwiz.contactInfoComboBoxTitle", "orderwiz.orderheadstep.contactwiz.contactInfoComboBox");
        initRolesCombo();

        setPersonCompanyComboDataSource();

    }

protected ComboBox getComboBox(String title, String inputPrompt)
{
    ComboBox dropDown = new ComboBox(DT.get(title));                
    dropDown.setFilteringMode(Filtering.FILTERINGMODE_OFF);     
    dropDown.setMultiSelect(false);
    dropDown.setNullSelectionAllowed(true);
    dropDown.setInvalidAllowed(false);
    dropDown.setNewItemsAllowed(true);
    dropDown.setInputPrompt(DT.get(inputPrompt));
    dropDown.setItemCaptionMode(ComboBox.ITEM_CAPTION_MODE_PROPERTY);
    dropDown.setItemCaptionPropertyId("myItemCaption");
    dropDown.setImmediate(true);
    dropDown.setWidth("100%");

    return dropDown;
}

private void setPersonCompanyComboDataSource() {
    if(myModel.getSelectedContactType() == TYPES.PERSON){
        setSelectedPersonComboDataSource();
    }else if(myModel.getSelectedContactType() == TYPES.COMPANY){
        setSelectedCompanyComboDataSource();
    }else{
        //we reset the comboboxes if there has been a reset or no value is selected in the search
        personCombo.setContainerDataSource(null);
        companyCombo.setContainerDataSource(null);          
    }
}


/**
 * Set the person combobox to hold the selected person and fills all related companies in the companyCombobox
 */
private void setSelectedPersonComboDataSource(){
    BeanItemContainer<PersonWrapper> personContainer = new BeanItemContainer<PersonWrapper>(PersonWrapper.class);
    personContainer.addItem(new PersonWrapper(myModel.getSelectedPerson()));
    personCombo.setContainerDataSource(personContainer);
    personCombo.setValue(personContainer.firstItemId());
    companyCombo.setContainerDataSource(new BeanItemContainer<CompanyWrapper>(CompanyWrapper.class));
    for(Company c : myModel.getCompaniesFromPerson(myModel.getSelectedPerson())){
        companyCombo.addItem(new CompanyWrapper(c));
    }
    if(myModel.getCompaniesFromPerson(myModel.getSelectedPerson()) != null && myModel.getCompaniesFromPerson(myModel.getSelectedPerson()).size() == 1){
        companyCombo.setValue(companyCombo.getItemIds().iterator().next());
    }
}

/**
 * Set the selected company to companyBox and fills all related persons to the personsCombobox
 */
private void setSelectedCompanyComboDataSource(){
    BeanItemContainer<CompanyWrapper> companyContainer = new BeanItemContainer<CompanyWrapper>(CompanyWrapper.class);
    companyContainer.addItem(new CompanyWrapper(myModel.getSelectedCompany()));
    companyCombo.setContainerDataSource(companyContainer);
    companyCombo.setValue(companyContainer.firstItemId());
    personCombo.setContainerDataSource(new BeanItemContainer<Person>(Person.class));
    for(Person p : myModel.getPersonsFromCompany(myModel.getSelectedCompany())){
        personCombo.addItem(new PersonWrapper(p));
    }
    if(myModel.getPersonsFromCompany(myModel.getSelectedCompany()) != null && myModel.getPersonsFromCompany(myModel.getSelectedCompany()).size() == 1){
        personCombo.setValue(personCombo.getItemIds().iterator().next());
    }
}
```

Comment: I dont see anything worng but missing lots of related code. It may be in the places you are posting. Have you tried to debug it and see the execution flow?

Comment: I have run a debugger. But there just isn't an event except if I do a null selection.

Comment: you may try to change the version of vaadin jar to see if same thing happens and if yes, maybe it is a bug

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**So I found out what the problem was. My entities provided an equals method that made all selections appear the same.**

In my entities I have an equals method that under normal circumstances would work correctly, but, my DB contained a lot of test data with copied Companies with the exact same data except for their ID, and the ID is not included in the equals method because of business rules (not my rules). So, when the combobox loaded all my companies and I made a single selection everything works but when I do another selection and the newly selected entity matches the old entity because of the equals method vaadin did not fire an change event since it was the same object according to my equals rules.

Comment: +1 good to hear that you found the problem and come back to post the solution.

Answer (score 0):

In my case I implemented getItemIds() and containsId() wrong in the custom container. The containsId() was a generated 'return false'. This also stops the selection listener from working.